# Correct way symlinking a folder into other folders dynamically

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder which contains my application. I then have a flexible number of folders in another directory, called “sites”. It looks like this:

```
+ -Application
+ -- Test.html
+ -- CSS
+ --- Style.css

+ -Sites 
+ --Site1
+ --Site2
```

I want to symlink all the files in the application folder into every folder found under the sites folder. So, the end result would look like this:

```
+ -Sites 
+ --Site1
+ -- Test.html
+ -- CSS
+ --- Style.css
+ --Site2
+ -- Test.html
+ -- CSS
+ --- Style.css
```

So I think the first step is loop for all folders found in the Sites folder, then to execute a symlink on everything in the folder. I cant really code but from my reading something like this might be a starting point?

```
find ./* -type d |
while read LINE
do
        echo ln -s /absolute/path/to/files/* "$LINE"
done
```

Comment: apache by default won't follow symlinks as a security measure... it might make more sense to accomplish this via aliases defined in httpd.conf so you're not wasting inodes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using Nginx however. The problem arises that even though each site has the "application", they each have a different config file. If you have any elegant ways to achieve this then I am all ears!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
for dir in Sites/*; do
    cd "$dir" && ln -s ../../Application/* . && cd -
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy and intuitive.
You can get it going inside each site and execute:

```
ln -s ../../Application/* .
```

You can run it for all "Sites" using AWK (from root directory):

```
ls -l | awk '$1 ~ /d.*/ && $NF !~ /Application/ && NF > 5 {system("cd "$NF" ; ln -s ../../Application/* .");}' -
```

Description: List files, get directories (/d.*/), ignore Application folder, go to each folder (cd $NF) and execute the "magic line".

Comment: You need to go up another level: `ln -s ../../Application/* .`